# JSR 181: error in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I got a strange error in my pom.xml. Maven (I'm using Maven 2) is signaling `Missing artifact javax.jws:jsr181:jar:1.0`, even if I get the corresponding dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr181</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What could possibly be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my repository, I think you want:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sun-jaxws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the solution to the problem. I think the way to find it could be interesting, too.

When I look on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/jsr181/1.0), the [pom file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jws/jsr181/1.0/jsr181-1.0.pom) on the repository pointed on an URL on bea.com, which is not available anymore. So I had to change to the [maintenance release](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/jsr181-api/1.0-MR1), like Brian Agnew suggested. And of course, update some other dependencies in my pom.xml, which needed the obsolete version in their own dependencies. Maven comes with a cost...

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/jsr181-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-MR1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, it really helped. I'd like to add that if one faces this issue when getting jsr181 jar as a dependency for a parent pom, say jaxws-api, you'd wanna exclude the missing jar from it : 

`<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsr181</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
         </exclusions>`